# UIView show/hide animation : hide animation does not seem to be working

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm trying to achieve `UIView` animation effects where the target `UIView` is triggered to be visible with animation options, and, when completed, it returns to the previous state of being hidden.

Below is the code I wrote, but there seems to be a problem. Because showing animation works perfectly fine, but when it comes to hiding the `UIView` disappears instantly, without intended hiding animation effects.

I tried to change `options` argument for `hideConsentView()`, but it does not change anything.

Am I missing something here?

```swift
var consentStatusView = UIView() 

func showConsentStatusView() {
    UIView.transition(with: consentStatusView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.consentStatusView.isHidden = false
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        self.hideConsentStatusView()
    })
}

func hideConsentStatusView() {
    UIView.transition(with: consentStatusView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.consentStatusView.isHidden = true
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine, no issue in the code, make sure you are not setting `consentStatusView.isHidden = true` or removing `consentStatusView` from some other code without animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply go with below function:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
   self.consentStatusView.alpha = 0 //If you show a view alpha = 1
}) { (finished) in
   self.consentStatusView.isHidden = true //If you unHide your view isHidden = false
}
```